# how to store mysql select statement inside php variable using mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, bcrypt

I know this has been asked before but I cant seem to fix my code.
What I need is to run some php code to query mysql using mysqli for a select statement to retrieve my bcrypt hashed pass so I can compare the user input with the user hashed password. NOTE: I have not yet added mysql_real_escape_string to my $POST variables.

I've changed this code a thousand times still cant get it.
Ive even copy and pasted to a new file a simple query script using num_row 
         and printf($row['pass']); used echo etc..... I've used fetch array ive tried almost everything I've been all via php mysql at php.net w3c.com etc etc is my system broke? Does mysqli have a bug ? and no i dont want to switch to PDO I wont stop til this is fixed and when there is no longer sql injection vulns 
Heres my code:

```
<?php
    $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'social');
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        exit("connection failed" . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    else
    {
        echo "connection established";
    }
    $db=mysqli_select_db( $conn,'social');

    if ($_POST && isset($_POST['submit'], $_POST['password'], $_POST['email']))
    {
        $pass = ($_POST["password"]);
        $email =($_POST["email"]);

        $bcrypt = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array('cost' =>  12));
    }
    $query = "SELECT `pass` FROM `social` WHERE `email` = 'jargon@jargon'";
    $fetcher = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
    echo $fetcher;

    if ($conn->query($fetcher) === TRUE)
    {
        echo "query has gone through now we need to store the hash<br /> for comparison";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "error did not retrieve hash info";
    }
```

Comment: You're setting a lot of variables but not using them. It's also not clear what your script is doing. It's obvious it's a login script but everything is hard coded and you're not actually doing any validation

Comment: no no validation yet i just care about storing the mysql select statement into the php variable so i can take the hash from database the use bcrypt verify similar to php.net

Comment: Also the variables set n not used is simply just because ive been at this for two days. you should of seen all the commented out code that i deleted befor posting this lol...

Answer (score 2):

```
$query = "SELECT `pass` FROM `social` WHERE `email` = 'jargon@jargon'";
$fetcher = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
```

Before you can `fetch` records from the result of the query, you need to actually perform the query. Your code should be

```
$query = "SELECT `pass` FROM `social` WHERE `email` = 'jargon@jargon'";
$result = $conn->query($query);  // This is where the query is executed
$fetcher = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

Two more points.

First, you don't need to call `mysqli_select_db`; you've already selected the database in your constructor call, so you only need to call `mysqli_select_db` if you want to access a *different* database.

Second, instead of calling `mysql_real_escape_string` you should look into using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-stmt.php), which do the same thing and also correctly handle type-matching and quoting.

Comment: the $db variable is old i havent taken it out yet i've changed this code 1000 times honestly. 2 days trying code over and over.  ive even had it the way you just said and returns null...

Comment: Post a description of the table `social`, please.

Comment: could my database be the problem ? I've been over most the tutorials on using mysqli... all i can figure is that the sql query isnt even going through like bad syntax or maybe php isnt proccessing it right.  ive even did a test with a simple script i copied and pasted and changed the database query to fit my db but still get errors ... ive called on name id email idk whats' wrong with this....

Comment: $table = "CREATE TABLE social (".
"id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,".
"name VARCHAR(25) not null,".
"pass VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, ".
"email VARCHAR(45),".
"reg_date TIMESTAMP".
") CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;";

Comment: It's possible. What happens when you type the query directly into your mysql client?

Comment: also used to return for email but now it wont and im sorry it returns error empty query im just burned out i dont want to just copy/past i wanna know whats up in the code 100

Comment: if you try it switch it to id that always returns pass in mysql client

Comment: ill post my registration code and login code if you want to try it i have come across what works on one system doesnt work on the next i dont know if that would have anything to do with standard code

Comment: " ive even had it the way you just said and returns null..." Do you mean `fetch_assoc` returns **`null`**?

Comment: PHP Warning:  mysqli::query(): Empty query in

Comment: Well, bleep! I was passing the wrong variable to `query()`! Check the edit I made to my answer and try it again.

Comment: I have a simpler code too that ik should work but doesnt i could post it too

Comment: i know i fixed it when i re implemented it

Comment: 2 days ive never once had this big of a problem programming lol if you have an email i could send you my errors and html/php/mysqli code and all the other codes ive tried in my original code they're all commented out... but still there

Comment: yea i caught your mistake i know these codes by heart now but dont know why they wont work i swear its the database....

Comment: sorry that comeon.php i sent you i never set the database on it returned the hash ha it should be $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '' , 'social') with this removed mysqli_select_db("social");   two days at this like i said i just need to take a break but im going to try and fix it tomorrow if you get my script working shoot it my way and thank, you for the help!!!!! sincerly Jargon.

Answer (score 1):

Try fetching the value from database after executing the query

```
$query = "SELECT `pass` FROM `social` WHERE `email` = 'jargon@jargon'";

$executedQuery = $conn->query($query);

if($executedQuery) {
    $fetcher = mysqli_fetch_assoc($executedQuery);
    echo "query has gone through ---------";
} else {
    echo "error did not retrieve hash info";
}
```

Comment: i had it set up like that befor i got null i dont know how many ways ive tried.

Answer (score 1):

```
    $query = "SELECT pass FROM social WHERE id = 11"; // took the (``) out of the query and added this im assuming the value is stored in the $row variable and I may be able to use $row with the user input to verify hash via bcrypt!!!
    $result = $conn->query($query);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
    {
    echo $row['pass'];
    echo "<br />";
    }
```

Comment: Took me a while to get so basic thing to work, that was helpful.